# How to get a file from a USB pendrive?

Tags: java, android

I have added a storage to my device as a usb pen drive and I don't know how I can get the file from usb.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices1 = new HashMap<>();
usbDevices1.clear();

if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
    boolean keep = true;
    for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
        device = entry.getValue();
        int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
        int devicePID = device.getProductId();
        if (deviceVID == 1659 && devicePID == 8963) {
            if (deviceVID != 0x1d6b && (devicePID != 0x0001 || devicePID != 0x0002 || devicePID != 0x0003)) {
                // There is a device connected to our Android device. Try to open it as a Serial Port.
                requestUserPermission();
                keep = false;
            } else {
                    connection = null;
                    device = null;
                   }

                   if (!keep)
                       break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use a library for this purpose..

Answer (score 1):

USB flash drive will your external storage device on your phone and you can read files from external storage using :

```
File path = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

Or use additional libraries:

https://github.com/magnusja/libaums